# How to resolve SQL Select Query Performance Issue for half million rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a smiple database structure but having alot of performance issues.
Kindly advise.

```
First table 

tblAvailableFormats(AvailableFormatsID bigint (PK),
BookID bigint (FK), FormatID int, EditionID int)
```

For every BookID there are multiple EditionID or you can say 12 rows for each BookID
with different EditionID (1,2,3....12)

```
Second table
tblRights (RightsID bigint(PK), AvailableFormatsID bigint (FK), RegionID int, StartDate datetime, EndDate Datetime, Comments varchar(2000))
```

For every "AvailableFormatsID" which is Primary Key of "tblAvailableFormats", there atleast 10 rows with different RegionID.

There are "128344" rows in tblAvailableFormats
There are "520830" rows in tblRights

When i just make simple inner join of these two tables, it takes around 3 minutes.
and if i use where clause, it gets more slow or if i use "IN" clause for fetching specific books data or use inner join of other tables, it gets worst. Kindly advise

```
Below is the sample query
Select * from tblAvailableFormats a Inner Join tblRight r On a.AvailableFormatsID = r.AvailableFormatsID
```

I am using

```
SQL Server 2008 R2
System Specs:
Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter
7.5GB RAM
Intel Xeon 1.8Ghz
```

Thank You

Comment: Do you have an index on `tblRight.AvailableFormatsID`?

Comment: No index on "tblRight.AvailableFormatsID", Only PK_tblRight(Clustered) index is defined.

Comment: Try adding a non clustered index on that: `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NCI_tblRight_AvailableFormatsID ON tblRight(AvailableFormatsID)`

Comment: Thanks i will try and let you know.

Comment: Yes, i applied indexing first on a copy of orginal table on friday. It worked better. And 
now at the moment it is good. Query executed in less time, but now i just applied indexing on live database table.
But its not that fast at the moment. Will indexing take some time for sorting?
Also any drawback of it? And do i need to Rebuild or Reorganize? 
Kindly explain
Thanks